# Google Drive API 'Pause'

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api

Is there a way to use the google drive desktop API/SDK to pause uploads? Similar to using the UI and hitting pause?

If that's not an option, is it possible to ensure that the app is idle from the API's and not currently syncing/uploading files ?